# Why does ingress on my Kubernates cluster doesn't respond on specified host, using nginx-ingress-controller?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

i'm noob on Kubernetes. I've configured Kube successfully on my Raspberry pi4b, using kubeadm. I created my first deployment using demo image that expose a simple page with some info and if I logs the pod it says that it listen correctly to the port 8080.

After installing nginx-ingress-controller (status is running) with helm following this https://limpygnome.com/2019/09/21/raspberry-pi-kubernetes-cluster/, I've created a service that points to deployment and an ingress as tutorial explains, but the host that I specified into that ingress is not reachable. Status is running for every pod but I don't understand how to fix it.

I don't know if the problem is the ingress-controller, the ingress or something else.

Here are my yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: hello

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello-world
  name: hello-world-deploy
  namespace: hello
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      # - image: docker:stable-dind
      - image: pmorjan/demo:latest
        name: hello-world
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello-world
  name: hello-world-service
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip: home-network
  namespace: hello
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 192.168.1.241

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  namespace: hello
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ciao.mirco.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /hello
          backend:
            serviceName: hello-world-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you have configure DNS records ?

Comment: @HarshManvar How can I check it?

Comment: How are you accessing it via curl? Have you made an entry in /etc/hosts

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I simply paste this ciao.mirco.com into the browser. No entry in etc/hosts

Comment: is this a real domain or just a sample? Have you created a nodeport/Loadbalancer type service for the nginx ingress controller ?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu it's the host that I've configured in the yaml into the ingress

Comment: it should have to be real domain or host address.

Comment: @HarshManvar ok, how can I do that? It would be ok also if It'will accessible only from my home network

Comment: you can patch service to cluster ip or node port and create ingress. and update etc/host.

Comment: @sP0re90 first try opening ip in browser and check it's working or not. 192.168.1.241

Comment: @HarshManvar it doesn't work

Comment: maybe there is some issue in service or pod connection or app inside pod not running properly.

Comment: @sP0re90 i think it's GOpher server running.

Comment: can you try removing LB from service and metallb annotation also. just simple clusterip service and try using ingress.

Comment: The los of the pods print that listen to 8080, It seems to work. 192.168.1.241  is an ip that I configured in the service but it's not the node ip. Is this a problem?

Comment: kubectl port-forward svc/hello-world-service 80:80. and open http://localhost:80

Comment: @HarshManvar yes if I forward the service it works! Now we know that the problem is the ingress, I'd like to use it instead the service. Any ideas?

Comment: change your service type and remove metallb and LB.

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello-world
  name: hello-world-service
  namespace: hello
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP

Comment: Done but I can't use the ingress to call the service with the hostname or the node ip

Comment: in ingress use any host name. in /etc/host add record which point to host.

Comment: @sP0re90 Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to access your pod via ingress you don't need to create a LoadBalancer type service for your pod. Instead you create a LoadBalancer type service for the ingress controller itself and a cluserIP type service for the pod. Also to  access it via ciao.mirco.com you need to add an entry into /etc/hosts file of the system where you are accessing as below.

```
ipaddress ciao.micro.com
```

The `ipadress` should be nodeip if you have created a Nodeport type service for ingress controller or LoadBalancer IP if you have created a LoadBalancer type service.

Create a NodePort service for nginx ingress controller in the namespace where nginx ingress controller is deployed.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

After this is created you can check the nodeport(ranging from 30000-32767) assigned to this service.

Find out the IP of the kubernetes node where nginx ingress controller pods are deployed.

Then you can access it via `nodeport:nodeip/hello` or `ciao.micro.com/hello` in your browser or via `curl nodeip:nodeport/hello -H 'Host:ciao.mirco.com'`

Comment: Could you give me an example based on my yaml, please? Thank you

Comment: Does to work if you just put the IP 192.168.1.241 in browser?

Comment: What is the output of kubectl describe svc hello-world-service -n hello. Add the output in question

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu i think maybe it cloud be issue of metallb using in service annotation & LB service type.

Comment: I think metallb is not needed at all..simple nodeport for ingress controller and clusterip for pod should work..but I am not familiar with raspberry pi

Comment: yes you are right there is no need of metal LB & LB.i have experience working with pi there should be no issue removing metallb.

Comment: I've removed annotations and load balancer and I've done a port-forward of the service to localhost and it works! I can si the Go application. How can we fix ingress, any ideas?

Comment: create a nodeport service for the nginx ingress controller as I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: Nodeport service is used instead of ingress? Sorry can you give me an example?

Comment: Nodeport will be used to expose the nginx ingress controller. Then you will able to access your pod via nginx ingress. Example yaml of nodeport for nginx added in answer

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I've created the nodeport replacing the name of my nginx ingress controller's namespace:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kube-ingress
  namespace: kube-ingress
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-ingress
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kube-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-ingress

Comment: If I kubectl get service on namespace now I see this:
kube-ingress                    NodePort       10.105.119.194   <none>          80:30550/TCP,443:31940/TCP   
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.104.178.243   192.168.1.241   80:30506/TCP,443:31204/TCP  
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.106.203.89    <none>          80/TCP

What ip and port should I use? If I use 192.168.1.100 (node ip) or 192.168.1.241 it doesn't work

Comment: 192.168.1.100:30550/hello

Comment: output of kubectl describe hello-world-service

Comment: Name:              hello-world-service
Namespace:         hello
Labels:            app=hello-world
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"hello-world"},"name":"hello-world-service","namespace":"...
Selector:          app=hello-world
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.106.28.251
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.32.0.4:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Comment: No errors. Only logs about events related to hello-world-ingress update. It logs when I run a new  kubectl apply command which updates the hello ingress

Comment: Interesting thing: I've tried to do a curl like this
curl -D- http://192.168.1.241 -H 'Host: ciao.mirco.com' and I receive the expected response. This works only if you're inside the node. So how you said before, we only need to find a way to call this load balancer from outside the node. Maybe the nodeport example that i posted was wrong? Or do we need a kube-proxy?

Comment: With curl -D- http://192.168.1.100:30506 -H 'Host:ciao.mirco.com' from localhost I received a 404

Comment: try this curl -D- 192.168.1.100:30506/hello -H 'Host:ciao.mirco.com'

Comment: I've tried in this moment and 192.168.1.100:30506/hello -H 'Host:ciao.mirco.com' works!

Comment: @sp0re90 I would appreciate if you accept and upvote my answer if it answered your question

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu done but maybe It can't be seen on the post because I've got less then 15 reputation. Thank you a lot for your patience, to all of you

Comment: @sP0re90 here you go more then 15 rep. hehe  :)

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu ahaha thank you. Only an information: now it works but I'm not using the nodeport  service that we created. We are using the port of the load balancer service, in fact I deleted the node port service and it still works. why?